# Redux Saga async/await pattern

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using async/await throughout my codebase. Because of this my api calls are defined by async functions

```
async function apiFetchFoo {
  return await apiCall(...);
}
```

I would like to call this function from my saga code. It seems like I can not do this:

```
// Doesn't work
function* fetchFoo(action) {
  const results = await apiFetchFoo();
  yield put({type: "FOOS_FETCHED_SUCCESSFULLY", foos: results});
}
```

However, this does work, and matches the redux saga documentation:

```
// Does work
function* fetchFoo(action) {
  const results = yield call(apiFetchFoo);
  yield put({type: "FOOS_FETCHED_SUCCESSFULLY", foos: results});
}
```

Is this the correct way to use Redux Saga alongside async/await? It is standard to use this generator syntax inside of the saga code, and the async/await pattern elsewhere?

Comment: Curious, in async/await pattern why are you using `function *() { ... await }` instead of `async function ()  { .. await ...}`? I'm pretty sure if you use await without async it leads to an error "await is a reserved javascript keyword".

Comment: Small side note: if you're using TypeScript and typedefs and you define the function as an asynchronous function like so: `async function* fetchFoo(action: requestAction): AsyncGenerator {`, you need to include `"es2018.asynciterable"` to your tsconfig's `compilerOptions.lib` array if you haven't already. Also, I needed TypeScript 3.7 (from 3.0).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, that's the standard way to use Redux-Saga.

You should never be calling the `await` function directly inside the saga-generator, because redux-saga is for **orchestrating** the side-effects. Therefore, any time that you want to run a side-effect you should do it by yielding the side-effect through a `redux-saga` effect (usually: `call` or `fork`). If you do it directly without yielding it through a `redux-saga` effect, then `redux-saga` won't be able to orchestrate the side-effect.

If you think about it, the redux-saga generator is completely testable without the need of mocking anything. Also, it helps to keep things decoupled: if your `apiFetchFoo` returned a promise, the saga would still work the same.

Comment: Can you include any links to documentation or github issues where this is discussed? What if there was a situation where the OP wanted to `await` a Promise that had no side effects? It seems like it would be a valid use case for async generators, but it doesn't seem like Redux-Saga allows for them.

Comment: @modulitos sure! https://redux-saga.js.org/ I am afraid that you don't quite understand what redux-saga is about. A redux-saga generator is meant for orchestrating side-effects. If you want to do something like what you are mentioning, then you shouldn't do it in a redux-saga generator... You could do it in a normal generator -if you want- or in another promise, it doesn't matter... and then just yield a `call` effect inside the redux-saga generator that calls that promise/generator/whatever.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! I think I was misunderstanding the boundaries of a redux-saga generator, and was trying to make it do more than it should. Instead, I should await the "no side-effect" promise in the entity that is being yielded into the saga generator.

Comment: Just for reference (may help others), here is good explanation from `react-saga` documentation of why we should not invoke asynchronous functions directly in saga: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html. As per this documentation, saga should yield effects to saga middleware and saga middleware will execute the effect and will hand over the result back to saga. Effects are simple JS objects telling middleware, what to do. This whole idea of yielding effects to saga middleware make unit-testing of saga simple, without mocking async things like API calls.

Comment: Lovely: **the redux-saga generator is completely testable without the need of mocking anything**

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Josep, `await` cannot be used inside a generator. Instead you need to use an [async function](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await#using-async-await). Also, note this is a limitation of async function itself. It is not imposed by redux-saga.

Beyond this, I also wanted to mention that it is a [conscious choice](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/987) by the redux-saga authors to *not* allow devs to express sagas as `async/await` functions.

Generators are more powerful than `async/await` and they allow advanced features of redux-saga like [co-ordinating parallel tasks](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/987#issuecomment-301039792).

Moreover, expressing sagas as generators help us define [Effects](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) which are plain objects defining the side effect. Effects makes it [very easy to test our sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html).

So, although your *working code* is fine, maybe not mixing up sagas and async function is a good idea.

Just define your `apiFetchFoo` to return a promise which resolves with the response to the request. And when this happens your saga will resume with the `results`.

```
 const apiFetchFoo = () =>
   fetch('foo')
     .then(res => res.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers says , Redux saga uses side effects which handles the async within it so the way of doing it , Is using yield and call if calling an API and so on so far

Answer (score -14):

`await` always work within a function that's declared as `async`. #thumbRule

```
async function fetchList () {
  let resp = await fetchApi([params]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not always the case.